# What is a good way to store metadata for an mp3 sound database in iOS?

Tags: ios, database, mp3

I will be writing a music program and need to store many sounds in mp3 format.  I anticipate needing some form of database containing information other than the sound itself so that the sounds can be used procedurally.  How can I do this so that (1) it is useful and convenient for me as I write my app, and (2) so that I can efficiently manage this sound database in my app, and scale it easily as I go.  Do I need a data structure that encompasses the mp3 file plus additional data, or is it possible to store the data elsewhere, cataloging the filenames and paths of the physical mp3s in this datafile?

There must be examples out there that have done this very efficiently - any suggestions or sample code I should study?

Answer (score 0):

Sound in DB??

- You may host the files in somewhere and download it ,Save the url
  path to the DB and work on
- Otherwise You need to store files in application in the filestructure
  itself add the filepath to db and fetch it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the information you need to store, each mp3 itself actually (potentially) holds the title, artist, album cover and more. In python there are a few modules for reading and writing this data, [mutagen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mutagen) being a pretty solid one.

```
sudo pip install mutagen
```